# Selecting all elements with a class containing specific text and removing them

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some object that's been added to the body of my page via a jquery plugin ... however I would like to get all the elements that contains specific text in the class ...

eg. class="genericforall****"

The part "genericforall" is repeated in the class of div elements and on a elements. I would like to call a jquery "remove" method on them to get rid of it.

My next part of this question is ... the reason why I want to do this is the fact that the plugin has no "recreate" method if I have loaded some elements with ajax after page load. So I would like to test (unless someone knows already) that if I removed them in this way and then call the "init" on the plug in again, if it would recreate itself including now the new elements that was created later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $("a[class*='genericforall'],div[class*='genericforall']").remove();
```

Comment: It is possible ignore case?

Comment: @FabianoLothor Hi, it's possible on some browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-case-insensitive

Comment: Thank you @TahaPaksu, I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

To select elements with an attr class that starts with genericforall:

```
$("a[class^=genericforall], div[class^=genericforall]").remove();
```